# Something breaks when Chrome developer tools are open

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

I made a quote generator and it works fine with the Chrome developer tools open, but then won't generate a new quote when the developer tools are closed. This happens with my project in CodePen. On my computer, it generates a quote three times (works fine the first three clicks of the generate quote button) then stops working. It's not working at all in Safari. Why would this be?

I'm sure my JavaScript could use some refactoring too, any help there would also be great. Thanks!

[Link to CodePen Demo](http://codepen.io/abharms/pen/yJORwN)

HTML

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Random Quote Generator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/quote.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:300italic,300' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>



</head>
<body>

    <div class="quote-container">
        <div class="quote" id="msg"></div>

    </div>
    <div class="button-container">
        <a href="#" id="button">Get Quote</a>
    </div>
    <div id="twtbtn"></div> 




<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/quote.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
body {
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0.5), rgba(0,0,0,0.5)), url('https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1437652010333-fbf2cd02a4f8?ixlib=rb-0.3.5&q=80&fm=jpg&crop=entropy&s=2330269f135faf1c33bf613b85d5f1df');
    background-size:     cover;              
    background-repeat:   no-repeat;
    background-position: center center; 
}

* {
    font-family: 'Lato', sans-serif;
}

.quote-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;    
}

.quote {
    width: 80%;
    text-align: center;
    margin: 0 auto;
    font-size: 48px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: white;
}

.button-container {
    margin: 30px auto 50px auto;
    text-align: center;
}

#button {
    border: 1px solid white;
    padding: 12px 30px;
    background: transparent;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 2px;
}

#button:hover {
    background-color: white;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
}

a:hover {
    color: black;
};
```

JavaScript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     //get quote from random quote API
      $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) {
      //append quote and author to document
      $(".quote").append(a[0].content + "<p>&mdash; " + a[0].title + "</p>")

      //initiate twitter button function
      window.twttr = (function (d,s,id) {
        var t, js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
        if (d.getElementById(id)) return; js=d.createElement(s); js.id=id;
        js.src="https://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js"; fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        return window.twttr || (t = { _e: [], ready: function(f){ t._e.push(f) } });
        }(document, "script", "twitter-wjs"));


      //insert tweet button
      insertTweetBtn();
    });
}); 

$("a").click(function(){
      //get quote from random quote API
      $.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1&callback=", function(a) {
      //replace HTML with newly generated quote
      $(".quote").html(a[0].content + "<p>&mdash; " + a[0].title + "</p>")
      //remove contents of tweet button div
      $("#twtbtn").empty();
      //insert new tweet button to grab newly generated quote
      insertTweetBtn();
    });
 }); 


function insertTweetBtn() {
    var msg = document.getElementById('msg').textContent;
    twttr.ready(function (twttr) {
            twttr.widgets.createShareButton(
                '',
                document.getElementById('twtbtn'),
                function (el) {
                    console.log("Button created.")
                },
                {
                    text: msg ,  
                }
            );
            twttr.events.bind('tweet', function (event) {
                console.log(event, event.target);
            });
        });

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok...so i was going crazy trying to figure it out then I went to the documentation for getJSON for jquery. I am not 100% about JSONP but thats the thing, when you add the &callback into the url..it uses JSONP. So I removed it and it works great in safari. Here is the codepen

[FIXED](http://codepen.io/carinlynchin/pen/qNqGBg)

and here is the quote from jquery:

"If the URL includes the string "callback=?" (or similar, as defined by the server-side API), the request is treated as JSONP instead. See the discussion of the jsonp data type in $.ajax() for more details."

```
$.getJSON("http://quotesondesign.com/wp-json/posts?filter[orderby]=rand&filter[posts_per_page]=1", function(a) {stuff}
```

This unfortunately doesn't explain why safari is the only one it didn't work in...but hey, it fixes it :)